# Stopping multiple setTimeout instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have the following problem:
I'm trying to implement a music application with javascipt and etc.
I've dissected the module architecture in Engine and UI. My Problem lies within the Engine Modules.
Basically I have a main Engine module

```
var NoteEngine = (function(){
    var that = {},
        matrices = [],
        beatCount = 1,
        globalBPM = 100,

    init = function(count){
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        context = new AudioContext();

        _registerListener();

        beatCount = count;
        matrices = [
            new NoteMatrix("piano", (16 * beatCount), globalBPM),
            new NoteMatrix("guitar", (16 * beatCount), globalBPM),
            new NoteMatrix("bass", (16 * beatCount), globalBPM),
            new NoteMatrix("bell", (16 * beatCount), globalBPM)
        ];
    },

    _registerListener = function(){

    };

    that.init = init;
    return that;
})();
```

A Class in order to load the sounds and create all rows

```
function NoteMatrix(instrument, colCount, bpm){

    var rows = [],
        matrixInstrument = instrument,
        bufferLoader,
        bufferList;

    _loadBuffer();

    function _loadBuffer(){
        var notePaths = _createNoteFilePaths();

        bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
            context,
            notePaths,
            _finishedLoading);
        bufferLoader.load();
    }

    function _createNoteFilePaths(){
        var basePath = "res/notes/" + matrixInstrument + "/",
            scale = ['C6', 'A5', 'G5', 'E5', 'D5', 'C5', 'A4', 'G4', 'E4', 'D4', 'C4', 'A3', 'G3', 'E3', 'D3', 'C3'],
            result = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            result[i] = basePath + scale[i] + ".mp3";
        }
        return result;
    }

    function _finishedLoading(buffer){
        $("body").trigger("MODULE_FINISHED");
        bufferList = buffer;
        _createMatrix();
    }

    function _createMatrix(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            rows[i] = new NoteRow(matrixInstrument, colCount, bpm, i, (i*colCount), (((i+1)*colCount) - 1), bufferList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and another subclass in order to manage a single row per instrument

```
function NoteRow(instrument, loopLength, bpm, row, minID, maxID, buffer){

    var noteBuffer = buffer,            // Notenklang in Bufferform
        gainNode = null,                // Hauptknoten für Ausgabe (auch lautstärke)
        volume,                         // Gesamtlautstärke
        notes = [],                     // Enthält alle Notenzustände in der Schleife (taktübergreifend)
        rowInstrument = instrument,     // Instrumentname in Stringform (für Abgleiche)
        timeoutID = null,               // Zuständig für Wiederholung/Stop der Schleife
        isPlaying = false,              // Status ob Schleife spielt oder nicht
        current16thNote = 0,            // Aktuelle Position in der Schleife
        rowBPM = bpm,                   // Tempo der Schleife
        scheduleDelay = 0,              // Verzögerung der Wiederholung der Planschleife (in ms) 
        scheduleAheadTime = 0.1,        // Abdeckung der Planschleife (in s)
        nextNoteTime = 0.0;             // Startzeit der nächsten Note

    _init();
    _registerListener();

    // Initialisiert die Notenreihe
    function _init(){
        gainNode = context.createGain();
        volume = 2.5;
        gainNode.gain.value = volume;
        for(var i = 0; i < loopLength; i++){
            notes[i] = false;
        }
    }

    // Registriert alle Listener für die Notenreihe
    function _registerListener(){
        $("body").on("CELL_CLICKED", _toggleNote);
        $("body").on("PLAY", _play);
        $("body").on("STOP", _stop);
        $("body").on("VOLUME_CHANGE", _changeVolume);
        $("body").on("BPM_CHANGE", _changeBPM);
        $("body").on("MUTE", _mute);
        $("body").on("RESUME_SOUND", _resumeSound);
        $("body").on("REFRESH_ALL", _refresh);
    }

    // Schaltet eine Note um
    function _toggleNote(event, data){
        if(data.instrument == rowInstrument && (data.id >= minID && data.id <= maxID)){
            console.log(data);
            notes[data.id - minID] = !notes[data.id - minID];
        }
    }

    function _play(){
        current16thNote = 0;
        nextNoteTime = context.currentTime;
        _startScheduler();
    }

    function _stop(){
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    function _handlePlayback(){
        isPlaying = !isPlaying;

        if(isPlaying) { 
            current16thNote = 0;
            nextNoteTime = context.currentTime;
            _startScheduler();
        }else{
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
    }

    // Schaltet die Notenreihe stumm
    function _mute(){
        gainNode.gain.value = 0;
    }

    // Stellt die ursprüngliche Lautstärke der Notenreihe wieder her
    function _resumeSound(){
        gainNode.gain.value = volume;
    }

    // Setzt die Notenreihe zurück
    function _refresh(){
        for(var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
            notes[i] = false;
        }
    }

    // Ändert die Lautstärke der Notenreihe
    function _changeVolume(event, data){
        volume = data/20;
        gainNode.gain.value = volume;
    }

    // Ändert das Tempo der Notenreihe
    function _changeBPM(event, data){
        rowBPM = data;
    }

    // Startet die Playback Schleife, die immer wieder abprüft, 
    // ob im vorgelegten Zeitraum eine Note abgespielt werden soll
    function _startScheduler(){
        while (nextNoteTime < context.currentTime + scheduleAheadTime ) {
            _scheduleNote(current16thNote, nextNoteTime);
            _nextNote();
        }
        timeoutId = setTimeout(_startScheduler, scheduleDelay);
    }

    // Spielt die Note und aktiviert die entsprechende Animation
    function _scheduleNote(beatPosition, time){
        if(notes[beatPosition]){
            var voice = context.createBufferSource();
            voice.buffer = noteBuffer;
            voice.connect(gainNode);
            gainNode.connect(context.destination);
            voice.start(time);

            $("#" + (minID + beatPosition)).addClass("animation");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#" + (minID + beatPosition)).removeClass("animation");
            }, 100);
        }
    }

    // Verschiebt die Position der Schleife nach vorne
    // Abhängig vom Tempo legt es auch das Interval zur nächsten Note fest
    function _nextNote(){
        var secondsPerBeat = 60.0 / rowBPM;
        nextNoteTime += 0.25 * secondsPerBeat;

        current16thNote++; 
        if (current16thNote == loopLength) {
            current16thNote = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem lies within the NoteRows. As you might see an object from the NoteRow class manages an entire row from a specific instrument with a specific note. Everything works just fine except I can't stop the playing loop with clearTimeout. Any advice? (likely without changing the entire architecture)

Comment: Can we see the entire animal somewhere ?

Comment: i dont think that would matter because the ui and the engine dont depend on each other in this problem. There is an older build (unfortunately withough any music function) under http://132.199.139.24/~krm22840/Note16/index.html

Comment: Let me quess, mme? ;P

Comment: you're goddamn right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all of your timeout functions to an array.

When you want to stop them, just do it like this:

```
function stopTrackedTimeouts()

{
    for(var i=0; i<timeouts.length; i++)
    {
        clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    }
    timeouts = [];
}
```

If you dont care about other timeouts running beside the ones you started, you can clear all timeouts by getting the the id of the latest timeout by adding a Null timeout.

```
function stopAllTimeouts()
{
    var id = window.setTimeout(null,0);
    while (id--) 
    {
        window.clearTimeout(id);
    }
}
```